# Installed blueman. Now Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: bluetooth, blueman

I was trying to get my Jabra earbuds to work. Installed `blueman` for help. Now when I switch on my computer, it takes me straight to command line.

So far I have tried the following:

- I removed blueman with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove blueman
  ```
- Then I autoremoved:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
  ```

Still when I boot it goes straight to command line.

I also get the following messages:

```
Failed to start studio system CPU governor setting. 
Failed to start service for snap application cups.cups-browsed.
Failed to start service for snap application cups.cupsd
```

I can't ping anything. I can't update or reinstall Ubuntu.

Not really sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Tried to access the `/var/log/apt/history.log` as [requested by user535733](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452507/installed-blueman-now-ubuntu-wont-boot#comment2537020_1452507) below, but I get the message access denied. Tried again as root with `sudo`, still denied access.

`apt-get update` gives the following:

```
E:Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open 13: permission denied
E: unable to open lock directory var/lib/apt/lists
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin Remove aches 13 permission denied
W: problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkcache.bin RemoveCaches 13 permission denied
```

I managed to access the logs folder but I'm not sure which file is relevant here. It contains the following files, some of which have the same filename but multiple versions so I've put numbers in brackets:

```
alternatives.log.(1:12).gz 
apport log.(1:7).gz
auth.log.(1:4).gz
boot.log.(1:7).gz 
bootstrap.log
btmp
btmp.1
Cups
Dist-upgrade
Dmesg.(0:4).gz
Dpkg.log
Dpkg.log.(1:12)
Faillog
Fontconfig.log
Gpu-manager.log
Installer
Kern.log.(1:4).gz
Lastlog
NordVPN
OpenVPN
Private
Speech-dispatcher
Stunne14
Syslog.(1:7)
Tallylog
Ubuntu-advantage.log
Ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.(1:6).gz
Unattended-upgrades
Upgrade
Windscribe
Wtmp
Wtmp.1
```

I couldn't find a way to fix this so I ended up installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu 22.4.01

Comment: You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1452507/edit) your question to include new info

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem: When I install the `blueman` package, it installs and works and does not destroy my system. Can you add the relevant section of your apt logs to your question above? (/var/log/apt/history.log). Also please add the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Done. Although I can't access the .log file.

Comment: Without information from the logfile we cannot help you, so figure out that problem. Your apt update output is also incomplete...and also shows unrelated problems that you need to figure out. Seems like you might be a fairly new or unskilled user. Just be patient and look up how to fix each problem as you encounter it. Most of what you have shown us so far looks self-inflicted, and avoidable in the future.

Comment: Try reinstalling Ubuntu. It will be simpler. You can use the live session to back up all the data you need

Comment: I can't reinstall Ubuntu, I've tried. I can't connect to any repositories now.

Comment: You don't need to connect to any repositories, you need to boot from a LiveUSB for that.

Comment: I managed to make a boot usb stick but it also doesn't work. I get the message no caching method found.

Answer (score 0):

You must have somehow remove core components of the GUI while purging the package.

You can reinstall the default GUI with

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work

Comment: "*it didn't work*" is much too vague to offer useful advice. *Something* must have happened. Keep in mind that we are not there in the room with you. You must fill in the details we lack.

Comment: Ok, well the first time it did nothing but today it is saying the following                                     
E: Failed to fetch http.... Could not resolve 'archive Ubuntu.com' this is the same for all packages it is trying to install.

Comment: There is no network connection.

Comment: Yes I can see that but how do I troubleshoot that and fix it? I can't ping anything but dig gives some results